# Subversion: more files than expected when merging a branch to trunk

Tags: svn, merge, intellij-idea

I have a branch than I want to merge to trunk.

- First of all I merge trunk into the branch, to have it updated.
- After that I update trunk (locally) also to have it with the last changes.
- Next step is to merge branch into trunk.

When I see files that have changed in my local trunk (before commit) I see that I have files from my project but also files that are not from my project.

Probably those files come from a bad merge from trunk to the branch.

What is the best option right now? Merge all files from the first revision of trunk to the branch(when the branch was created) ? I think I will get a lot of conflicts this way.
Create a new branch from trunk and put in this branch files from my project? This means doing again testing.

Any ideas?

thanks for your time

Edit: only commit files of my project could be the best/fastest solution ?? (90 files to commit only 45 files are from my project)

Comment: In common case your step 2 was mistake: you have to collect all changes to the moment of merge in trunk, merge trunk to branch (after it branch contain *only local* changes), merge branch to trunk

Comment: I added the word locally in step 2. regards

Comment: Lazy what u told me is what I made. In the last step after merge branch to trunk, I see the changelist I see more files than I was expecting.

Comment: Anyway it's at least "not ideal" - I always merge (and prefer do it this way) subtrees without local changes , can't recall "why"

Comment: Ok, try (without merge) `svn diff --summarize BRANCH-URL TAG_URL` and check every file in resulting list "Why it's here?" (it will be again diff for `M` files and log for `A` and `D`)

Comment: `--dry-run` option for merge is also useful in debug

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those files that have been *changed*, are the content of the files modified, or is their property values modified?

Whenever I hear of someone telling me that a merge changed too many files, I find the problem is usually with the `svn:mergeinfo` property. Subversion tracks merges by setting this property. If you always do merging at the root of the project, only the root directory will have this property set, and all files will share it. If you do individual file merges, all of these files will have a `svn:mergeinfo` property set, and every time you do a merge, each of those files will be *modified* since the `svn:mergeinfo` file on all of these files also must be modified.

Whatever you do, don't revert those files in order to eliminate the merge. That simply makes things worse. The `svn:mergeinfo` will show those files haven't been merged for those revisions, and the next time you do a merge, Subversion will redo the merge, and update the `svn:mergeinfo` once again.

Comment: the content files is what has changed. Why not revert files that I don't want to commit/modify in trunk?? I want only to commit files developed by me conciously.

Comment: If it's the content of the files that has been changed, you can revert them. I was referring to times when only the value of `svn:mergeinfo` itself has changed, but not the content.

Comment: yes David is the content that has changed, the best options seems that is to commit to trunk as a result of merge, only the files that are from my project, reverting the others in the changelist. right?

Comment: The thing you must be careful is that the files you revert will still show as being merged since it will use the svn:merge of a directory higher in the directory hierarchy since these files don't have merge information on them.