# subversion commit adding more files than what is expected by "svn merge"

Tags: svn

note: my steps are different than [This Stack Overflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13743823/subversion-more-files-than-expected-when-merging-a-branch-to-trunk)

```
1. svn merge -c  261588 https://svn.repo
2. svn commit -m 'message...' (Committed revision 261598.)
```

and notice that instead of the ONE file , 20 other files are also submitted

so i revert :

```
svn merge -c -261598 https://svn.repo
svn commit -m 'reverted 261598'
```

now if i try to commit on a fresh working copy of the repo, i STILL get the SAME issue of submitting more files than what i expect. 
How can i merge this ONE file and not all these others.

Comment: Well, merging the way you do explicitly asks for the whole repository getting merged. Address the file you want to merge directly in the merge commands url.

Comment: @arkascha not sure if i am merging the whole repo, since i DO mention the revision #

Comment: No, I was not referring to the revision. I referred to all files changed in that revision. Those are the files you merge. All of them. If you want only a single file out of that bunch of files altered in that revision you have to address that single file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read up on the [`svn merge`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.merge.html) syntax. You should specify the path to the file you want to merge, both on the server URL and the WC_PATH (working copy path). If you don't, then Subversion assumes you want to merge at the folder level.

```
C:\SVN\MyProject> svn merge -c 261588 path/to/file.ext https://127.0.0.1/svn/MyRepo/Projects/MyProject/path/to/file.ext
```